# CATScript - Text, Lines and Frames in Black

Tags: vbscript, colors, 2d, catia

The code is as below (CATScript):

```
Sub CATMain()
    '   enter sheet background
    Set oView = oDrawingDocument.DrawingRoot.ActiveSheet.Views.Item("Background View")
    oView.Activate

    '   select all views in current screen
    Set oSelection = oDrawingDocument.Selection
    oSelection.Search "Type=*,scr"

    '   set visual to black
    oSelection.VisProperties.SetRealColor 0, 0, 0, 0

    '   exit sheet background
    Set oView = oDrawingDocument.DrawingRoot.ActiveSheet.Views.Item("Main View")
    oView.Activate
End Sub
```

The code works seamlessly except that `oSelection.VisProperties.SetRealColor 255, 255, 255, 0` does not change any of the selected lines and frames to black in my 2D drawing. Manually I can do this so pretty sure I'm just using the wrong syntax. `SetVisibleColor` neither works, but then also I can only find that these syntaxes are used for changing color in 3D and I am using it for a 2D drawing. Anyone here knows the syntax to manipulate the color icon in the 'Graphic Properties' workspace for a 2D drawing?

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/interfaces/interface_VisPropertySet.htm) you appear to be making the right call. Wonder if perhaps it is a layering issue, do you need to set a specific layer before specifying the colour? I could be way off as I've never used CATIA so take my guesswork with a pinch of salt.

Comment: @Lankymart Manually I just enter the sheet background, select the whole sheet (just like the code does), select black in the 'Graphic Properties' workspace and everything is black. With the code line as I have it now, no single color is being changed. The layer is on 'None' during the manual and script process.

Comment: @Lankymart Also I checked if the selection is even registered by using oSelection.Count after activating oSelection.Search "Type=*,scr". This gives back "11".

Comment: In that case, I would suggest looping through the Selection object *(using a `For Each` loop)* and output what objects are being selected to confirm they are the expected objects in the selection. At the moment, there are just too many assumptions being made.

Comment: @Lankymart the following objects are selected (information gathered with a loop as you pointed out): 1. Point2D (1x) - 2. Line2D (2x) - 3. DrawingComponent (5x) - 4. DrawingText (4x).

Comment: @Lankymart Got it to work. I used the following:
`Set oSelectionDC = oDrawingDocument.Selection`
`oSelectionDC.Search("CATDrwSearch.DrwText,all")`
`oSelectionDC.VisProperties.SetRealColor 0,0,0,0`
`Set oSelectionDT = oDrawingDocument.Selection`
`oSelectionDT.Search("CATDrwSearch.DrwTable,all")`
`oSelectionDT.VisProperties.SetRealColor 0,0,0,0`

Comment: @Lankymart the same could be done with lines using `oSelectionGI.Search("CATDrwSearch.CATEarlyGenItem,all")` but I skipped this due to the time it takes to run. Assuming the designer already draws with black lines.

Comment: @Lankymart although my account exists for a while I am pretty new to the posting/answering. Thanks for the tip, I will definitely change it! And another thanks for thinking along for a solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found after some research and trial&error:

```
'CHANGE LINE COLOR
Set oSelectionGI = oDrawingDocument.Selection               
oSelectionGI.Search("CATDrwSearch.CATEarlyGenItem,all")     
oSelectionGI.VisProperties.SetRealColor 0,0,0,0

'CHANGE TEXT COLOR
Set oSelectionDC = oDrawingDocument.Selection
oSelectionDC.Search("CATDrwSearch.DrwText,all")
oSelectionDC.VisProperties.SetRealColor 0,0,0,0

'CHANGE TABLE COLOR
Set oSelectionDT = oDrawingDocument.Selection
oSelectionDT.Search("CATDrwSearch.DrwTable,all")
oSelectionDT.VisProperties.SetRealColor 0,0,0,0
```